Returning multiple pandoc action in lua filters
This is a lua filter created by me personally, capable of extracting images synthetically created with TikZ (no already existing imported images), and converting them into a .png file via ImageMagick.
The image, as you know, can be inserted into the .docx file using the pandoc.Para command. I need to know if, in addition to importing the image, it is possible to write a string just below the newly imported image
My Minimal Working Example:
function RawBlock(el)
    if string.find(el.text,"\\begin{tikzpicture}") then
        io.output("C:/Logs/output.tex")
        io.write("\\documentclass{standalone}", "\n")
        io.write("\\usepackage{tikz}", "\n")
        io.write("\\usepackage{pgfplots}", "\n")
        io.write("\\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}", "\n")
        io.write("\\usepackage{siunitx}", "\n")
        io.write("\\begin{document}", "\n")
        io.write(el.text, "\n")
        io.write("\\end{document}", "\n")
        io.close()
        os.execute("cd C:/Logs & pdflatex output.tex & convert -density 288 output.pdf -alpha off -resize 35% output.png")
        print(el.content)
        return pandoc.Para({pandoc.Image({},"C:/Logs/output.png")})
    end
end


Instead of a pandoc filter, you could use the tikz externalize library to generate png versions of your tikz pictures. Section "52.7 Bitmap Graphics Export" of the tikz user guide has an example. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350081/36296

Yes, I know the alternative way to export TikZ images. What I actually need is execute two pandoc command. one for inserting image return pandoc.Para({pandoc.Image({},"C:/Logs/output.png")}), and another immediately following to insert a generic string. How can I do this?

If I understand correctly, then you want to return two blocks instead of one. That's possible by returning a list of blocks, e.g.
return {
  pandoc.Para {pandoc.Image({}, "image.png")},
  pandoc.Plain "This follows right after the image."
}


P.S. do you know a way to automatically center both pictures and text inside .docx file?

Not sure if it works, but you could try to use a Figure element (requires pandoc 3.0 or newer): return pandoc.Figure({pandoc.Image({}, "image.png"), "Figure caption") and then use a reference doc to get the figure centered.
